# Sql server takes too long time for update query to execute for few rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

UPDATE table1 SET col1='True'
This query takes more than 30 secs for about 6000 records. Why is it so slow?

Comment: Check if some other operation is blocking. It might simply be that
some other process is holding a lock on the table, preventing
you from updating.

Comment: It may be useful to add a SHOW CREATE TABLE for this table to your question.  It sounds a bit odd.  Also are other queries/updates slow?  If so it may be a database configuration issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a trigger?

And see my answers here too: [Why does an UPDATE take much longer than a SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009659/why-does-an-update-take-much-longer-than-a-select/2009693#2009693)

Comment: I had trigger, temporarily turning off the trigger  did the magic.

ALTER TABLE table1 DISABLE TRIGGER ALL 
UPDATE table1 SET Col1='True' 
ALTER TABLE table1 ENABLE TRIGGER ALL